# Have multi phase build use same branch as triggering build

Tags: azure-devops

I have a two builds in my pipeline for different solutions within the same repository. Solution1 is triggered by commits in git, and Solution2 is triggered whenever a build of Solution1 is complete.

The problem I am having is that my initial git trigger is looking for any branch that matches the pattern of `release/*`. That works as intended, but the Solution2 build is just using whatever is configured as the Default branch in the "Get sources" task on the build pipeline. I have to set that default to a branch, can't use a pattern.

I initially set this up with both triggering from git with the `release/*` pattern, that worked but since I only have one build agent it caused issues occasionally where the release step would trigger before both builds were completed. Trying to configure this multi phase build so I can just trigger the release on the last build phase.

Is there a way to have my build on Solution2 still be triggered by build completion but use whatever branch triggered the build of Solution1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** 
Install https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks

**Then**
If you switch off Solution2 triggering

**Finally**
Edit Solution 1 pipeline and configure the new the "Trigger Build" task at the end of the pipeline.

Then when solution1 completed it will trigger Solution2 from that task, against the same branch.